# Firebase Authentication Custom Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm using Android Studio to create an App where is possible for users to get registered and to log in.

To do that I want to use Firebase authentication, so I clicked on the "Tool" section in android studio, and then on "Firebase". I selected "Authentication" from the menu and among the possible choices I choose "Custom Authentication System".

It was then told me to follow the steps that you can find [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/custom-auth) under the section "Before you begin".

I followed everything and I downloaded the json file containing my account's public/private key pair (point number 2, letter c) but I have no clue where I have to copy it.

The instructions say "Copy this file to your authentication server" but I don't have an Authentication server, I wanted to do everything through Firebase.

Can someone help me and tell me where I have to copy this file, or if there's a way I can implement the Authentication system only using Firebase and no other external server?

-- **EDIT** --

For anyone interested, I figured it out thanks to a tutorial on Youtube.

Simply ignore the passage (point number 2, letter c) and click on "Set Login method" on Firebase in the section Authentication.

Choose the "email and password" method, and that's it.

Everything will be done through Firebase.

Comment: What are you wanting to do? That option needs an auth server that you set up. If you want to go through firebase and nothing else, choose one of the other options.

Comment: Since you are using Java, I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) will help.

Comment: I wanted to make the users login with username and password, but I saw online tutorials that used the option with the Authentication through "email and password". However this option is not showing in my list of options. I only have the Authentication through "Google Sign-In" and "Facebook Login".
I don't know if through "Google Sing-In" users must register using
exclusively a gmail email, because I didn't want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I figured it out thanks to a tutorial on youtube. Simply ignore the passage (point number 2, letter c) and click on "Set Login method" on Firebase in the section Authentication. Choose the "email and password" method, and that's it. Everything will be done through Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I figured it out thanks to a tutorial on youtube. Simply ignore the passage (point number 2, letter c) and click on "Set Login method" on Firebase in the section Authentication. Choose the "email and password" method, and that's it. Everything will be done through Firebase

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).